# Get system ip code not working in server

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code works on my system not in server please help me to fix this error. am not sure what is error..

This is my partial code...

```
private IPAddress getMyCurrentIP()
{
     IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

     if (host.AddressList.Length == 1)
     myCurrentIP = host.AddressList[0].ToString();
     else
     {
        foreach (IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
        {
          if (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
          {
            if (IsLocal(address))
            return address;
         }
      }
  }


  return null;
}

  public bool IsLocal(IPAddress address)
  {
  if (address == null)
  throw new ArgumentNullException("address");

  byte[] addr = address.GetAddressBytes();

  return addr[0] == 10
  || (addr[0] == 192 && addr[1] == 168)
  || (addr[0] == 172 && addr[1] >= 16 && addr[1] <= 31);
  }
```

please help me to fix this error...

Comment: And this code is broken... how? My crystal ball is in the shop today...

Comment: When there is only one IP in the list, why are you not checking AddressFamily and IsLocal. Debug is the only real waty to fix this, seing as it depends on the machine is set up, but there would appear to be gaps in your logic large enough to drive a bus through.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing the given code would compile, since you never declare `myCurrentIP`. Also, if there is only one item in the `host.AddressList`, your function would still return null.
Re-write the first condition like this:

```
if (host.AddressList.Length == 1)
{
    return host.AddressList[0];
}
else
{
    ...
```

That would return the first and only IPAddress of the system if that condition is met.

Comment: mycurrentIp as a string that is declare global. The above code works fine in my system. And didn't work in server. please help me to fix this error

Comment: @FDO you need to give more information. What is not working? Is there an exception? does the function not return the expected IPAddress? You need to be specific. Without more info, the only thing I can suggest is to check your DNS settings on the server. Those would be a likely source for problems in your code.